# Solaris/UNIX: Does snoop have the potential to slow down network traffic?

Tags: networking, performance, bottleneck, snoop, buffer

This is the way I see it.

A copy of the network activity is written to a buffer, and `snoop` reads from the buffer. As long as snoop is able to get the data out fast enough (writing directly to a file is faster than writing to a terminal or a `bzip`er), then the buffer will never fill up.

But if there is a high volume of network activity, and `snoop` can't write it out fast as it comes in (for whatever reason), then `snoop` has to wait, therefore the original buffer gets full.

If the buffer gets large, what happens?

- In favor of maximum throughput, the buffer grows, indefinitely. `:-/`
- In favor of low memory usage, some data might be excluded. `:-o`
- In favor of stable results, the network I/O is bottle-necked until there is more room in the buffer. `B-)`

I am particularly interested in Solaris, but information on other UNIX systems would be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that packets get dropped by snoop in favour of not delaying them during times of high activity.

Snoop provides the -D switch to display the number of packets dropped during capture.

The  `-s snaplen` switch can be used to truncate packet capture after `snaplen` bytes and means there is less chance of buffer overflow during high traffic periods.

The warnings section of the man page says this too

> The processing overhead is much higher for realtime packet interpretation. Consequently, the packet drop count may be higher. For more reliable capture, output raw packets to a file using the -o option and analyze the packets off line.